# How can I add something to my code so there are no repeats every 6 times when it adds to a list?

Tags: python, list

Me and a buddy of mine are just beginners trying to make something so we don't have to make the list by hand but we cant figure out how to make the code does not repeat the first 5 letters of a name for at least for the next 5 names added to the list

```
import random

num_in_list = int(20)

data = [

]

blacklist = [

]

preferred = [

]

not_preferred = [
  
  ]

def generate_list(num_in_list, blacklist, preferred):
  list = []

  while len(list) < num_in_list:
    index = random.randint(0, len(data) - 1)

    data = data[index]

    if name not in blacklist:

       if data in preferred:

         if random.random() < 0.75:

           list.insert(0, data)
       else:

         if random.random() < 0.50:
           list.insert(0, data)
         else:
           if data in not_preferred: 
             if random.random() < 0.25:
               rotation.insert(0, data)


  return list

list = generate_list(num_in_list, blacklist, preferred)
```

I tried searching around but it is too hard for me to understand and cant figure out how to implement other peoples solutions.

Comment: You really don't want to use `list` or `map` as variable names. While at the same time you have 5 things that have names but are undefined.

Comment: Yes thanks, I miss labelled a few of the variables

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the solution down into steps:

1. Generate a starting name (and store its first 5 letters)
2. Generate 4 more names (making sure not to generate names with the same first 5 letters)
3. Repeat step 1 until you have enough names

```py
import typing
import random

def generate_names(n: int) -> typing.List[str]:
    l: typing.List[str] = []
    while len(l) < n:
        new_name: str = random.choice(NAMES)
        first_five: str = new_name[0:5]
        l.add(new_name)
        for _ in range(0, 4):
            non_similar_name: str = random.choice(NAMES)
            while non_similar_names.startswith(first_five):
                non_similar_name = random.choice(NAMES)
            l.add(non_similar_name)
    return l
```

Comment: Is it then possible for me to instead of generating a name, use a name from a data set (from the variable) and store the first 5 letters. Then in step 2 pick 4 more names making sure not to pick ones with the same starting 5 letters.